# Django template include a template with a variable coming from view

Tags: django

I have problem with Django templates. I want to create a base html, which I will use to display posts. I call a template from view, which includes an html file, where the file extends the base html.

> **view**
>
> ```
> def main(request):
>     all_posts = News.objects.all()
>     return render_to_response("index.html", {'all_posts': all_posts})
> ```
>
> **template** -- index.html

```
<div id="content">
    {% include 'content.html' with posts=all_posts%}
</div>
```

> **content.html**

```
{% extends "content_base.html" %}

{% for post in posts %}
    {% block date_of_post %} {{ post.date }} {% endblock %}
    {% block post_author %} {{ post.author }} {% endblock %}
    {% block post %} {{ post.content }} {% endblock %}
{% endfor %}
```

> **content_base.html**

```
<div class="post">
    <h2 class="title"><a href="#">{% block blabla %}{% endblock %}</a></h2>
    <p class="meta"><span class="date">{% block date_of_post %}{% endblock %}</span><span class="posted">Posted by <a href="#">{% block post_author %}{% endblock %}</a></span></p>
    <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="entry">
        <p>
            {% block post %} {% endblock %}
        </p>    
        <p class="links">
            <a href="#" class="more">Read More</a>
            <a href="#" title="b0x" class="comments">Comments</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it seems like I cannot pass the *all_posts* variable to **content.html**. What is the problem here? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the loop into `index.html`, and include `content_base.html` directly. So index.html becomes:

```
<div id="content">
    {% for post in posts %}
        {% include 'content_base.html' %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

and content_base.html is

```
<div class="post">
    <h2 class="title"><a href="#">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
    <p class="meta"><span class="date">{{ post.date }}</span><span class="posted">Posted by <a href="#">{{{ post.author }}</a></span></p>
    <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="entry">
        <p>
            {{ post.content }}
        </p>    
        <p class="links">
            <a href="#" class="more">Read More</a>
            <a href="#" title="b0x" class="comments">Comments</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is still `{% endblock %}` tag left in your `content_base.html` please remove it.

Answer (score 2):

You're using blocks with identical names, because you're using them in a loop:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% block date_of_post %} {{ post.date }} {% endblock %}
    {% block post_author %} {{ post.author }} {% endblock %}
    {% block post %} {{ post.content }} {% endblock %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can't do that. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6427336/203535).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes too much normalization is not so good. You can simply have `index.html` and all of your code can go there (avoiding unnecessary blocks).

```
<div id="content">
    {% for post in all_posts %}
        <div class="post">
            <h2 class="title"><a href="#">{{post.title}}</a></h2>
            <p class="meta"><span class="date">{{post.date}}</span><span class="posted">Posted by <a href="#">{{post.post_author}}</a></span></p>
            <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="entry">
                <p>
                    {{post.content}}
                </p>    
                <p class="links">
                    <a href="#" class="more">Read More</a>
                    <a href="#" title="b0x" class="comments">Comments</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I'm going to use the content_base.html in a huge number of pages, so I have to do it like this way ;)