# Django: Use block in multiple places?

Tags: django, jinja2

This is the template I've written

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block body %}
    <div class="row hide-on-mobile" style="height: 100vh">
        <div class="col-auto p-5">
            <img src="{% static 'logo.svg' %}" class="mb-5 hide-on-mobile" style="height: 84px"/>
            {% block form %} {% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div class="col bg-brown p-5">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-between" style="height: 100%">
                <h1 class="text-blue mb-3">It's always Ups<br>and Downs</h1>
                <img src="{% static 'investing_illustration.svg' %}" class="auth-illustration"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hide-on-desktop" style="height: 100vh; position: relative">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column bg-brown h-100 p-3 align-items-start">
            <img src="{% static 'logo.svg' %}" class="mb-3 hide-on-desktop" style="height: 56px"/>
            <p class="text-blue mb-3">It's always Ups<br>and Downs</p>
            <img src="{% static 'investing_illustration.svg' %}" class="auth-illustration"/>
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; z-index: 99; background: white; width: 100%">
           <div class="d-flex flex-column p-4">
               <p class="mb-4">Login</p>

               {% block form %} {% endblock %}
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I inherit this template in a page as follows:

```
{% extends 'auth_base.html' %}
{% block form %}
    <p class="mb-4">Login</p>

    <form class="pb-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password">
        <a class="text-blue">Forgot Password?</a>
        <button type="submit" class="mt-3 btn btn-primary full-width">Login</button>
    </form>

   <div class="text-center">
        <span>New Here? <a class="text-blue">Create an account</a></span>
   </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The `form` block is used two times..because when I inherit the template I want to write only once..but display it in two different places in the same page. In this case, I've written different layouts for mobile and desktop show the user actually sees only once.

However, this code doesn't work and gives the following error:

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: 'block' tag with name 'form' appears more than once
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to include partials multiple times. Partials work differently then blocks - not via inheritence, so you would have to change your template code a bit.

You would need to create a partial template for your form which would expect a certain context (the `form` probably), and you would include that template snippet twice in your main template:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column p-4">
    <p class="mb-4">Login</p>
    {% include "_partials/login_form.html" %}
</div>
```

`_partials/login_form.html` would basically contain what you had now inside your `form block`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#include

EDIT: as someone else pointed out - the question on multiple blocks with the same name has already been addressed before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6427336/8401179

Comment: Thanks...this seems to work but there is one more problem I'm facing. I am extending the template in another template and I would like to pass a block of code from the inherited template. How would I do that?

Comment: @GoutamBSeervi you can create a new question on SO and put in more details if it was not yet asked. It sounds like it would warrant its own question, and I'm not sure I understand it without knowing more details.

Comment: Actually I did post a new question here with more details, do let me know if I've missed any other details:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67068284/django-use-blocks-in-multiple-places-inside-template

Comment: @GoutamBSeervi the other question looks like a duplicate of this one - you said you are facing "one more problem" but it looks like the same problem? You need to clearly state two different questions, or the other question risks to be closed as duplicate.